# Intellij IDEA: view class methods in their real order

Tags: intellij-idea

I am switching to IntelliJ IDEA from Eclipse. Currently I am using IDEA v 12.0.4.

In Eclipse when you called Class Outline view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) you saw methods in the order they are declared in the class. While the similar File Structure view in IDEA (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) lists methods in the alphabetical order which I find less convenient for myself in some cases.

Is there a way in IDEA's File Structure popup to see class methods listed in the order they appear in the class? Ideally I would like to have a possibility to switch from alphabetical to natural ordering.

Comment: I created a ticket for this on their youtrack. [Go vote](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154161)!

Comment: This appears to be solved. The selected order type is persisted through sessions now.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the  **"Structure" tool window** ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on OS X) instead of the "File structure" popup.

Comment: And also click on the upper-right gear to check that "Sort Alphabetically" is not enabled :)

Comment: Thanks, that gives an answer! A bit pity this is not doable from the popup though.

Comment: Fields are still grouped separately from methods (and stuck below the methods, unlike most programming conventions).  Sigh.

Comment: @preeze agreed; why not allow it *also* in the popup? Furthermore, who even wants to use those docked windows? (you can make them float but they still don't behave like popups). I also moved from Eclipse recently, and it seems to me that JetBrains are making a habit of only half implementing features and not fully understanding UI for developers.

Comment: I am also frustrated by the fact that in `File Structure` - `CTRL + F12` you can not permanently change the order of how is shows the functions...
By default it's alphabetically!
Even if I click on the settings-wheel icon and I un-check `Sort Alphabetically` , the next time I open this pop-up, it is again Alphabetically sorted!

What a shame!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a feature that allows both "by appearance" order and omitting the grouping of members/fields and methods. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732526/114626), in a duplicate of this question:

> You can find the settings icon on right top of the project window, there you can find the option as below, to get the natural order.
>
> `sort by type`

According to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-tool-window.html) though, this feature should do something else entirely:

> If the option is off, the items (files, classes, etc.) are sorted alphabetically. If the option is on, the files are sorted by their extensions. The `.java` files appear in the following order: interfaces, classes, enumerations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Structure tool windows in the `Floating` mode.
Then use `Alt+7` instead of `Ctrl+0`.

Comment: For those who might want to do this - the floating mode does not behave the same as the pop-up dialog, unfortunately. It does not disappear when it loses focus, it also does not disappear when you choose an element and want to jump onto it in the editor. You have to manually close the dialog.

Comment: @MartinMelka which version of IDEA are you using? But yeah, it's a bit of a trade-off

Comment: using 2019.1 EAP