# Don't show class members in alphabetical order in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Scala in Intellij, and on the project panel it would show the members of a  class, but it is sorted in alphabetical order. How can I see it in natural order (the order in the source code)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA: view class methods in their real order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357923/intellij-idea-view-class-methods-in-their-real-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the settings icon on right top of the project window, there you can find the option as below, to get the natural order.

> sort by type

Answer (score 0):

In the Structure Tool Window you can view the class members in natural order (it has a toolbar button to sort alphabetically also).

Comment: But I mean in the project panel.

Comment: AFAIK what you want is not possible in the project panel.